# How to show progress during app startup in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, xamarin.forms, doevents

I have a Xamarin Forms app that needs to perform a sequence of long-running operations during startup. I would like to inform the user of progress, using a page with a simple status message which changes as the sequence progresses.

The sequence of operations is implemented as a set of asynchronous methods, which I have wrapped in an async container method that also contains the code to update the UI. Here's a simplified version:

```
private async Task DoStartupSequence()
{
    SetStatusMessage("Step 1");
    await DoStep1();
    SetStatusMessage("Step 2");
    await DoStep2();
    SetStatusMessage("Step 3");
    await DoStep3();
    SetStatusMessage("Completed");
}
```

However, regardless of how I invoke the sequence, the UI doesn't get updated until execution of the sequence is complete.

I have tried running the sequence on its own thread from within the `App` constructor:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Task.Run(() => DoStartupSequence()).Wait();
}
```

I have also tried invoking the sequence asynchronously from within the `OnStart` method:

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
    await DoStartupSequence();
}
```

In a WinForms app, this problem might be solved using `Application.DoEvents` (although I understand that this approach has its own problems). In any case, Xamarin Forms doesn't appear to support anything like this.

This seems like such a common requirement that I imagine there must be a standard pattern for its implementation. Does anyone know what it is?

Many thanks,

Tim

**Update**: In response to suggestions from @BraveHeart, I am able to further simplify my test code to show what's not working properly.

The following sample references 2 static pages, each containing just a label. The 1st page announces the start of a long-running sequence and the 2nd page announces its completion. My goal is to see these 2 pages rendered with a 1-second delay between the first and the second. In practice, what happens is that I never see page 1, because both pages are rendered together.

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var navigationPage = new NavigationPage();

    MainPage = navigationPage;

    navigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new TestPage1(), false).Wait();

    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();

    navigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new TestPage2(), false).Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing in the UI should be only via the UI thread .

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Task.Run(() => DoStartupSequence()).Wait();
}
```

This piece of code here tells the program to create another Task (thread) to perform **DoStartupSequence()** including **SetStatusMessage()** which I assume it just sets a content of a label or something like that and **DOES NOT** have other awaiting stuff in it.

So try to make it like this

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StartupSequence(); 
}

private async void StartupSequence()
{
    SetStatusMessage("Step 1");
    await DoStep1();
    SetStatusMessage("Step 2");
    await DoStep2();
    SetStatusMessage("Step 3");
    await DoStep3();
    SetStatusMessage("Completed");
}
```

I think this would solve your problem. However, My recommendation is to put the code of **"DoSteps"** and in the viewmodel level, and bind the content of the label to a property in the viewmodel this way your code behind would be much cleaner and you do not have to worry about the threads, *I think*.

Another point I have managed to note is the naming conventions. In short words Anything that is awaitalble should get a name+"Async" as postfix so it would be

```
await DoStep1Async();
```

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. My code samples above were simplified, but my real code does correctly use view models and async naming conventions in the way that you describe. However, it is essential that my async methods are executed asynchronously. If I call them in the way that you have shown, the bits that are explicitly asynchrounous (e.g. HTTP API calls) fail to execute.

Comment: can you make a sample generating the problem in a github so we can have a look at it ? 
Note I personally can only use android if the problem is there i can help you

Comment: I have updated my question to show the most simple case I can imagine that demonstrates the problem. This sample doesn't even attempt to deal with the problem of calling async methods - everything is synchronous - but it still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Apologies for wasting your time. I have just re-tested my simplified sample using the async pattern that you recommended and it works! Clearly, I still have some other problem in my real-world app, but your technique does indeed solve the problem described in my question. Thank you.